# Font changes on hyperlinks with href='#' in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, fonts, hyperlink, href

I've been searching all over for a resolution to this issue, but for the life of me I can't find anything.

Essentially, on every hyperlink on a page that self references (some are collapsible panel extenders, others use JS to open a popup, etc.) the font changes for the hyperlink after it is clicked. This is only occurring in IE8.

Example:

(Apparently I can't post images, so here's some links to the images. You may want to download and open them side-by-side as the difference is not extremely clear when looking at them individually.)

[Pre-Click Hyperlink Image](http://i1090.photobucket.com/albums/i363/jegibson0322/pre_click_zps35a16ace.png)

[Post-Click Hyperlink Image](http://i1090.photobucket.com/albums/i363/jegibson0322/post_click_zpsf85e9354.png)

The font does not return to normal once the element loses the focus, nor does the font become distorted if you give focus to the element via keyboard navigation so I don't think that it is related to selecting the hyperlink.

Further, hyperlinks with an href that doesn't self-reference do not change fonts when clicked.

I also don't think that it is the a:visited CSS as refreshing the page causes the font to go back to normal.

Has anyone ever experienced this? I can't seem to find anything that is related to this issue. Any help is appreciated.